# e.charcode in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I dont undertand why this does not work

```
const addRate = (e: { charCode: KeyboardEvent }) => {
 if (e.charCode >= 48) {
      ...
 }
}
```

I get this:

```
'Operator '>=' cannot be applied to types 'KeyboardEvent' and 'number'.ts(2365)'
```

But `e.charcode` is indeed a `KeyboardEvent` and this works somewhere else on my app

```
const addString = (e: { target: HTMLInputElement }) => ....
```

Comment: *"But e.charcode is indeed a KeyboardEvent"* No, `e` is a `KeyboardEvent` (assuming you use this for a keyboard event, not `change`). `e.charCode` is a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. It's `charCode`, not `charcode`.
2. You've applied the parameter type incorrectly, it should be:

   ```
   const addRate = ({ charCode }: KeyboardEvent) => {
   ```

   You need to apply the event type  to the entire parameter you're destructuring.

Note that `charCode` is deprecated (though it'll never actually go away), new code should use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) and/or [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) (depending on the event).

---

In the comments, you've asked how you'd "do this" with a `change` handler. But the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) isn't a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), it's just an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) (actually, React's types define a `ChangeEvent` for it, presumably so `type` is the string literal type `"change"` rather than a string). Then you said you wanted to handle both.

You can do that by specifying that the event is either `Event` (or, in React, a `ChangeEvent`) or `KeyboardEvent`, and then branching based on whether it's a keyboard event:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, KeyboardEvent } from "react";

function Example() {
    const addRate = (e: ChangeEvent | KeyboardEvent) => {
        // ...code that doesn't care which event it is...
        if ("key" in e) {
            // Here, TypeScript will kow that `e` is a `KeyboardEvent`
            // ...code that needs to know the `code` or `key`...
        }
    };

    return <input type="text" onChange={addRate} onKeyDown={addRate} />;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCAFigHYDmSAogG5IlZwDSSAngEYQpQAmNd8AXzgAzKBBBwARFFQZJAbgBQi4QFcSGYBBJxKADxTgANkgAUASlyK4NuGm0BneCm7cEKGEjgBeOKaQAXATE5FS09HAAPkysHFy84TCW3gB8VrYZcAD0WXAAdAX23F4wxPDcEEgOJADk8GhcXgDuhMBohHBIiXDA8MAOBXnWmTbAwn6SANaskj06SJY4wyMZOXAAEkgy2AAqLGBIAMpoUMBg8E3ARkZwkxBNcKUecAAGSC89DnAor8zsnDw+PQXssVjY1oMiiUynASEgkNwvjAILcSPdHoQvC8oR9oK9piwXoNQRkBKCBEpQTIYKooDoADzAEhgVTwGD7JDeSSePQwWbaIikCjeHAuNweJBCbR-AAi9xIIrF7k8QiyKSUZKAA)

Comment: [MDN says it's deprecated anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) and e.code should be used instead

Comment: @LucaKiebel - True, though there's no chance it'll ever actually go away. :-D I've updated the answer, though, it's a good point.